# Strange behaviour of QML Text

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

When I'm running following simple example:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Popup {
        width: 100
        visible: true
        contentItem: ColumnLayout {
            Rectangle {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                implicitHeight: 50
                color: "red"
            }

            Text {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                text: "some very very very very very very very very very very very very long text"
                wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following warning: `qrc:/main.qml:12:5: QML Popup: Binding loop detected for property "contentHeight"` and `Popup` detects height incorrectly:
[image]

Maybe problem connected with `Text`'s `implicitHeight` so it has some dependency on `ColumnLayout`'s `implicitHeight` but I can't understand why.

Can anybody explain me how binding loop appears and how to solve it?

Comment: I do not understand what is causing the problem but if a height is placed on the Popup the warning disappears.

Comment: I know that it is possible to remove this warning with explicit `height` property but I need to resize popup height depending on content size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
Popup {
    width: 100
    visible: true
    contentItem: Column {

        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            implicitHeight: 50
            color: "red"
        }

        Text {
            width: parent.width
            text: "some very very very very very very very very very very very very long text"
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        }
    }
}
```

About the warning:
It looks like a Bug, But I guess it's not. If two rects won't have that warning.

And remove `Layout.fillWidth: true` of Text also won't have.
So Text's height needs ColumnLayout's width and ColumnLayout expand height by Text's height. Feel like a paradox that two components require the size of each other.

Update:

```
Popup {
    width: 100
    visible: true
    contentItem: ColumnLayout {
        width: parent.width
        Rectangle {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            implicitHeight: 50
            color: "red"
        }

        Text {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            text: "some very very very very very very very very very very very very long text"
            wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, solution works, but I don't fully understand explaining. `Text`'s height needs `ColumnLayout`'s width, thats clear, but `ColumnLayout`'s width is fixed by `Popup`'s explicit width (as I understand [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qml-qtquick-controls2-popup.html#popup-layout), and `Text`'s height should't depend on `Popup`'s height.

Comment: @KamilZaripov The point of the problem is `Layout.fillWidth` belong to `ColumnLayout` but not `Text`, so the flow of binding may not go like `Text` require `ColumnLayout` finally require `Popup` width. When `ColumnLayout` ask for `Text` height, the `Text` said "No, you shall tell me your width first because I need to `fillWidth` then decide the height". See my update.